# Laratrust ошибка route:list

Tags: laravel, route, artisan

```
 Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

  Target class [App\Http\Controllers\UsersController] does not exist.

  at C:\htdocs\www\rpc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:807
    803|
    804|         try {
    805|             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    806|         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  > 807|             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    808|         }
    809|
    810|         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    811|         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))

  2   C:\htdocs\www\rpc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:805
      ReflectionException::("Class App\Http\Controllers\UsersController does not exist")
PS C:\htdocs\www\rpc>
```

Возникает данная ошибка при выполнении artisan route:list

**UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use App\Role;
use App\Permission;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('role:users');
    }

    // Index Page for Users
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::paginate(10);

        $params = [
            'title' => 'Users Listing',
            'users' => $users,
        ];

        return view('admin.users.users_list')->with($params);
    }

    // Create User Page
    public function create()
    {
        $roles = Role::all();

        $params = [
            'title' => 'Create User',
            'roles' => $roles,
        ];

        return view('admin.users.users_create')->with($params);
    }

    // Store New User
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->input('password')),
        ]);

        $role = Role::find($request->input('role_id'));

        $user->attachRole($role);

        return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', "The user <strong>$user->name</strong> has successfully been created.");
    }

    // Delete Confirmation Page
    public function show($id)
    {
        try {
            $user = User::findOrFail($id);

            $params = [
                'title' => 'Confirm Delete Record',
                'user' => $user,
            ];

            return view('admin.users.users_delete')->with($params);
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $ex) {
            if ($ex instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
                return response()->view('errors.' . '404');
            }
        }
    }

    // Editing User Information Page
    public function edit($id)
    {
        try {
            $user = User::findOrFail($id);

            //$roles = Role::all();
            $roles = Role::with('permissions')->get();
            $permissions = Permission::all();

            $params = [
                'title' => 'Edit User',
                'user' => $user,
                'roles' => $roles,
                'permissions' => $permissions,
            ];

            return view('admin.users.users_edit')->with($params);
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $ex) {
            if ($ex instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
                return response()->view('errors.' . '404');
            }
        }
    }

    // Update User Information to DB
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        try {
            $user = User::findOrFail($id);

            $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,' . $id,
            ]);

            $user->name = $request->input('name');
            $user->email = $request->input('email');

            $user->save();

            // Update role of the user
            $roles = $user->roles;

            foreach ($roles as $key => $value) {
                $user->detachRole($value);
            }

            $role = Role::find($request->input('role_id'));

            $user->attachRole($role);

            // Update permission of the user
            //$permission = Permission::find($request->input('permission_id'));
            //$user->attachPermission($permission);

            return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', "The user <strong>$user->name</strong> has successfully been updated.");
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $ex) {
            if ($ex instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
                return response()->view('errors.' . '404');
            }
        }
    }

    // Remove User from DB with detaching Role
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        try {
            $user = User::findOrFail($id);

            // Detach from Role
            $roles = $user->roles;

            foreach ($roles as $key => $value) {
                $user->detachRole($value);
            }

            $user->delete();

            return redirect()->route('users.index')->with('success', "The user <strong>$user->name</strong> has successfully been archived.");
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $ex) {
            if ($ex instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
                return response()->view('errors.' . '404');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас роутер ищет класс **Controllers\UsersController**, а должен **Controllers\Admin\UsersController**. Проверьте указан ли `namespace` для маршрута.